# mvc orderby<.IorderedEnumerable> error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

MVC beginner.
In implementing a solution from another post, I now have a different problem. I understand the gist of the problem, but do not understand how to fix it.

I've changed a sort to a groupby:

```
ViewModel.Lots = from x in (db.Subdivisions.SelectMany(sd => sd.Lots))
group x by x.Num_of_steps == 0 ? 3 : x.Num_of_steps < 115 ? 1 : 2 into g
orderby g.Key
select g.OrderBy(g1 => g1.LotName);
```

I now get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<MVCBSV.Models.Lot>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MVCBSV.Models.Lot>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

After reading several posts I've made some changes such as:

```
  select g.OrderBy(g1 => g1.LotName).AsQueryable().ToList()
```

In this case the message changes to:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.List<MVCBSV.Models.Lot>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MVCBSV.Models.Lot>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can someone help- and explain why they did, where they did it so I can understand.
Thanks

Comment: The two error messages you specify are the same. Is one of them meant to be different?

Comment: Similar but not exactly the same. after I added .tolist the second message changed from .Linq.IOrderedEnumerable to .Collections.Generic.List

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewModel.Lots = (from x in (db.Subdivisions.SelectMany(sd => sd.Lots))
        group x by x.Num_of_steps == 0 ? 3 : x.Num_of_steps < 115 ? 1 : 2 into g
        orderby g.Key
        select g.OrderBy(g1 => g1.LotName).ToList()).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

You need to get a `IEnumerable<Lot>`.`g.OrderBy(g1 => g1.LotName)` returns a `IOrderedEnumerable<MVCBSV.Models.Lot>` for each group.So first, you should flatten your results with `SelectMany` and then use `ToList`.The last `ToList` might be unnecessary in this case, anyway...

Comment: Intellisense liked it. I'll run it in the morning.